# Интерфейс Traversable

Tags: php

Привет.Встетил такое понятие.Может кто-то примером показать что это за чудо?

**Интерфейс, определяющий, является ли класс обходимым (traversable) используя foreach.**

Это класс ,которой создает объекты ,для которого можно использовать цикл  foreach для обхода свойств?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Интерфейс](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.interfaces.php) - не класс. Это контракт на реализацию методов. Если класс реализует интерфейс, то в нём обязательно должны быть методы, перечисленные в интерфейсе. Концепция интерфейсов позволяет обойти неприятности, связанные с множественным наследованием.

Теперь про Traversable. Если почитать [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.traversable.php), то можно найти следующие строки:

> Это внутренний интерфейс, который не может быть реализован в скрипте PHP. Вместо него нужно использовать либо [IteratorAggregate](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.iteratoraggregate.php), либо [Iterator](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.iterator.php). При реализации интерфейса, наследующего от Traversable, убедитесь, что в секции implements перед его именем стоит IteratorAggregate или Iterator.

По сути, это просто общий предок интерфейсов Iterator и IteratorAggregate, который позволяет абстрагироваться и работать с обоими интерфейсами одинаково.

Comment: Iterator extends Traversable ....

Comment: @zloctb, прошу меня простить, мои телепатические способности сегодня барахлят. Что именно вы хотели сказать столь глубокомысленным комментарием?

Comment: Для себя напоминание на будущее....